# How to set target fragment

Tags: android

I have two fragments: the fragmentA and the dialogFragmentB in one Activity. 
fragmentB has two alertDialogs, it starts from dialogA and then dialogA call dismiss() and generates dialogB.
fragmentA has method onActivityResult() and dialogB (from dialogFragmentB) has to send some intent-result there after button's click. But before i send that result i have to set target fragmentA. How to do it in onClick method of dialogB?

i think i need something like this:

```
public void onClick(){
     ...
     dialogB.dismiss();
     fragmentA.setTargetFragment(FragmentA, requestCode);
}
```

But i have an Error: cannot find symbol variable FragmentA

Thank you!

Comment: You dismiss dialogB and start the fragment in onDestroy of your dialogB.

Comment: i don't know how to set target fragmentA from fragmentB:
???.setTargetFragment(???, requestCode);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved my problem in next way:

```
public class DialogFragmentB extends DialogFragment{
   ...
   public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle b){
   // here i create two dialogs, first dialogA and then it calls dialogB
   // finally dialogB has to return his datas and datas from dialogA in fragmentA
      ...
      public void onClick(View v){
         ...
         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         // these two code's lines resolved my headache --------------
         Fragment ft = fm.findFragmentByTag(FragmentA.FRAGMENT_A_TAG);
         ft.setTargetFragment(ft, FragmentA.CODE_REQUEST);
         // ----------------------------------------------------------
         dialogB.dismiss();
         sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myData);
      }
      return dialogB;
   }
   // And here myData goes in onActivityResult in fragmentA
    private void sendResult(int resultCode, MyData myData){
        if(getTargetFragment() == null){
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE_2, myData);
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the variable reference instead of the class name:

```
public void onClick(){
     ...
     dialogB.dismiss();
     // note the lowercase "f"
     fragmentA.setTargetFragment(fragmentA, requestCode);
}
```

Comment: In this way how the fragmentA can be initialized or how to get the instance of FragmentA in onClick method of dialogB?

Comment: This returns something like: Setting OkDialogFragmen as the target of OkDialogFragmen would create a target cycle.

Comment: @Juan Giorello this may happen if you use an extension function e.g run Kotlin standard function. The setTargetFragment function checks whether this scope is a targetFragment, so you cannot use it. Try using let which sends the scope as a parameter, instead of calling on itself.
The reason for checking the target cycle is not clear, but hopefully, Google will address this issue in the future.